# PowerShell Firewall Management

Tags: windows, firewall, powershell, windows-firewall

I have a bunch of machines that I need to enable Remote Scheduled Tasks Management (RPC), Remote Scheduled Tasks Management (RPC-EPMAP), and Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI-in) on for GPO Updates.

I would like to run a PowerShell script so I do not have to do this manually. However, I am new to powershell.

Is there a way I can get the powershell command when I add the rules manually at a machine?

EDIT:

This is one way I found to do it:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Remote Administration" new enable=yes
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="File and Printer Sharing" new enable=yes
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Remote Service Management" new enable=yes
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Performance Logs and Alerts" new enable=yes
Netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Remote Event Log Management" new enable=yes
Netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Remote Scheduled Tasks Management" new enable=yes
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Remote Volume Management" new enable=yes
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Remote Desktop" new enable=yes
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Windows Firewall Remote Management" new enable =yes
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="windows management instrumentation (wmi)" new enable =yes
```

However, I have to execute it on every machine.

For some reason, this one does not work:

```
Enable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup “Windows Remote Management”
```

Comment: You didn't want to use the Starter GPO I linked to in your previous question and/or create a GPO to do this for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working on Windows Server 2012 R2 Core, this worked for me:

```
Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "File And Printer Sharing" -Enabled True
```

Here is how to check if it was succesful

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "File And Printer Sharing"
```

And find the value in "Enabled", it should be set to TRUE.

More info and arguments can be found here:

[Set-NetFirewallRule Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj573828.aspx)

Comment: To enable it for specific access (i.e. domain, public, private networks), add the -Profile Domain|Public|Private argument.

Answer (score 3):

According to this article on Technet, only on Server 2012 or Windows 8: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831755.aspx

Windows 7 and Server 2008 require Netsh, even with Powershell 4.0.